# Git user protocols

Tags: git

According to [git-push man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching and rsync can be used for fetching and pushing, but these are inefficient and deprecated; do not use them).

Say I want to broadcast this via [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). Or maybe push it to a database via [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). Or maybe send it to another application via [JRMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Remote_Method_Protocol). Or zip the file and use [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) to send it to a friend. You get the gist.

Is this baked in into git or is there a relatively easy / supported (i.e. there's interface) way to add additional / user protocols to git? If so, any documentation / tutorial links would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `.git/objects`, which contains blobs, trees, commits, and tags. Doing any kind of `git push` basically involves 3 steps:

1. Finding out what objects the remote needs, but doesn't already have;
2. Packing (de-duplicating) these objects to save space; and
3. Transferring the objects.

`git rev-parse --verify HEAD` and [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) can help you with steps 1 and 2.

---

Read more:   [Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)  ·  [Git's Little Bundle of Joy](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html)